# Using getElementByID.innerHTML from within a switch statements case?

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Alright so first off, total Newbie here, so my questions answer might be extreemley simple because i have missed some thing critical.

I am trying to have a switch statement, switch out the innerHTML of an h1 tag with an id="bbref". I set the userName Variable to "Lister" and created my switch statement to write a different line into the h1 tag base don what name was input for userName.

for some reason however my code is just not working... any thoughts.. or noticeable brain-farts on my end?

here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Javascript Learning</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var userName = "Lister";
switch (userName) {
    case "Lister" :
    document.write.getElementById("bbref").innerHTML = "Lister Is the Man!";
    break;
    case "Rimmer":
    document.write.getElementById("bbref").innerHTML = "Rimmer is a Smeg head...";
    break;
    default :
    doacument.write.getElementById("bbref").innerHTML = "It's all about \"The Cat\""
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
    <section>
        <article>
            <h1 id="bbref">Test Title</h1>
        </article>
    </section>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're messing up your functions a little there, change:

```
document.write.getElementById("bbref").innerHTML = "Lister Is the Man!";
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("bbref").innerHTML = "Lister Is the Man!";
```

And so on for the rest.

`document.getElementById("bbref")` will fetch the element and `.innerHTML` will be the HTML inside the element, changing it will directly change the visible HTML. So there's no need to `write` anything.

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/H4hzE/

---

**window.onload/$(document).ready()**

The other issue you would be having here is that your javascript code is executing before your HTML is rendering. Bind your code to `window.onload` or `$(document).ready()` (if using jQuery) to run the code after the page loads.

**window.onload Examples:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload

**jQuery's $(document).ready():**
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

**Fiddle (using window.onload):**
http://jsfiddle.net/H4hzE/1/

---

Since you say you're new to JavaScript, it's probably worthwhile sharing some info regarding `document.write()` as I think you may have misunderstood it's functionality a little bit. :)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp
http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write

Comment: Thanks everyone. I now have my code showing:

`var userName = "Lister";
switch (userName) {
 case "Lister" :
 document.getElementById("bbref").innerHTML = "Lister Is the Man!";
 break;
 case "Rimmer":
 document.getElementById("bbref").innerHTML = "Rimmer is a Smeg head...";
 break;
 default :
 document.getElementById("bbref").innerHTML = "It's all about \"The Cat\""
}`

but still nothing. I thought that the .write was pointless, it was one of the many iterations I was trying. but to no avail. Thoughts?

Comment: @CaderialJeffS I just updated my answer with details regarding `window.onload` and jQuery's `$(document).ready()`. The problem is your javascript is running before your HTML is rendered.

Comment: BAM! That did the trick, it is very much appreciated, now i can go hammer the dent out of my forehead from all the banging it against the wall.

Answer (score 1):

document.write() and document.getElementById() are two different methods. In this case you just want to use getElementById, so omit the .write in all 3 cases, e.g.:

```
document.getElementById("bbref").innerHTML = "Lister Is the Man!";
```

Comment: Thanks , I removed the excess .write method but still nothing is happening...? the help is appreciated.